# "The method 'cast' isn't defined for the type 'Object'" when reading from Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I create banner in listview and get the data from firebase database.

```
Future<List<String>> getBaners(DatabaseReference bannerRef){
  //The method 'cast' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
  return bannerRef.once().then((snapshot) => snapshot.snapshot.value!.cast<String>().toList());
}
```

Comment: What does the data at `bannerRef` in your database look like?

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
Future<List<String>> getBaners(DatabaseReference bannerRef)async{ 
  final DataSnapshot res = await bannerRef.get();
  if(res.exists)
    return res.value as List<String>;
  return [];
}
```

I am willing to help more if you can provide more details about the structure of the data that bannerRef is pointing to.

Comment: The return type 'String' isn't a 'FutureOr<List<String>>', as required by the closure's context.

Comment: Future<List<String>> getBaners(DatabaseReference bannerRef){


  return bannerRef.once().then((snapshot) => snapshot.snapshot.value! as String);
}

Comment: Error is not resolved after it

Comment: What is the String that you get from the database?

Comment: I have to load the data from from firebasedatabase and store the values in firebase firestore.

Comment: void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    final FirebaseDatabase _database=FirebaseDatabase(app: widget.app);
    _bannerRef= _database.ref().child('Banners');
  }

Comment: body: FutureBuilder<List<String>>(
        future: getBaners(_bannerRef!),

Comment: I have updated the solution, it might work for you know, however, it is more likely that you will get a Map<dynamic,dynamic> object from the firebase get() function, depends on the structure of the data.

Comment: final FirebaseApp? app;
  final String title;